# Print PDF with Acrobat Pro: select printer

Tags: c#, pdf, acrobat

I can print a PDF with Acrobat (not the reader)
Here is the code:

```
var mApp = new AcroAppClass();

var avDoc = new AcroAVDocClass();
if (avDoc.Open(filename, ""))
{
    var pdDoc = (CAcroPDDoc)avDoc.GetPDDoc();
    avDoc.PrintPagesSilent(0, pdDoc.GetNumPages()-1, 2, 1, 1);
    pdDoc.Close();                    
    avDoc.Close(1);
}    

if (mApp != null)
{
    mApp.CloseAllDocs();
    mApp.Exit();
}
```

This will print the PDF to the default windows printer.
Is there a way to choose the printer without changing the windows default printer?

Comment: Can we use this to flatten and save as a different pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation:
http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf

It seems this is not possible:

> PrintPages always uses the default printer setting.